# I don't find kurento-module-platedetector for Node.js Module - Plate Detector Filter

Tags: kurento, kurento-media-server, fiware-kurento

I followed the tutorial Node.js Module - Plate Detector Filter of Kurento. When I go to https://localhost:8443/ then I press the start button but an error appears that says "Error message from server: Could not find media server at address ws://localhost:8888/kurento. Exiting with error SyntaxError: Module 'platedetector' is not installed in the Kurento Media Server".

I tried to install kurento-module-platedetector but it says it doesn't exist.